# In ESRI Collector, is there a way download/sync a layer that has attachments without attachments, but still allow for the adding of them?

Tags: arcgis-collector

We have data collectors using ESRI collector all across a state.  Every morning they have to download a new work area - World Topo basemap, plus slice of one layer (attribute data focused), and a slice of another layer (picture/attachment focused).

We wanted to try and eliminate the download portion each morning, giving our teams and extra 15-30 minutes every day.  We found we could create a basemap of the entire state at a high enough resolution (Problems using REST API to generate Tile Packages from World Topo (For Export) ), and we can download the attribute specific layer for the entire state (takes 5-10 minutes) but we can't download the picture focused layer (pics are tie to the attribute layer through IDs we create and maintain / geographic location), because of the sheer size (GBs) of pics that would need to be downloaded. Is there a way to download an attachment enabled layer within collector, such that:
We don't download any of the attachments when defining the work area and doing the initial pull/sync
But can still upload new attachments to the points created in the layer that get synced at the end of the day?

Anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

You can change offline settings of the web map you are using in collector:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide a little more clarity to Anastasia's answer:

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/take-maps-offline.htm

**Options for editable layers**

In the Editable layers section, specify which types of data users retrieve from the server. Edits are always sent to the server each time the user synchronizes data. By default, both features and attachments are retrieved.

**Features**

Leave *Features* checked if users need to see the features in a work area when a map is first downloaded in addition to new and updated features after syncing. This option results in slower performance and increased storage usage for the initial download and subsequent sync operations, but it delivers all the features in a work area.
If users do not need to see existing features when they first download a map or update features they are not working with when they sync, uncheck this option. This decreases the amount of data transferred. New features are always uploaded during sync.

**Attachments**

Leave *Attachments* checked if users need to see them. This increases the size of the data you retrieve with the initial download and synchronizes with the server.
Uncheck Attachments if users do not need to see these to complete their work. Attachments will not be downloaded, which decreases storage on your mobile device and decreases the time it takes to download and sync. New attachments are always uploaded during sync.

---

**Options for read-only layers**

In the Read-only layers section, you only specify whether users will retrieve attachments from the server for noneditable layers. Features in read-only layers are always retrieved. Uncheck Attachments when users do not need to see attachments associated with read-only features. Users still see read-only assets, but data size and transfer time costs are reduced because users do not sync attachments.